# Linux Debian memory leak?

Tags: linux, debian, memory

I am running an application which needs to be restarted everyday. I am noticing that when I close this application and I run "free -m" It says:

```
          total       used       free      shared       buffers        cached 
Mem:      1009        863        146       0            16             815

-/+ buffers/cache:    31         978
Swap:     0           0          0
```

How come I only have 146mb free? It is the only application I am running and when I restart the whole system I have 980mb free.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/85470/meaning-of-the-buffers-cache-line-in-the-output-of-free

Comment: What is the application ?

Comment: @Jeffrey It's srcds_linux.

Comment: Try testing your app with valgrind or similar.

Comment: You actually have 978 MB free.  It is normal that the system will fill up the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not panic, all is fine. [Here](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) is explanation why:

Excerpt:

To see how much ram is free to use for your applications, run free -m and look at the row that **says "-/+ buffers/cache"** in the column that **says "free"**. That is your answer in megabytes:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1504       1491         13          0         91        764
-/+ buffers/cache:        635        869
Swap:         2047          6       2041
```